# Save listbox to SQL database, "Procedure or function Music_Add has too many arguments specified"

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

[Here is the stored procedure on my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43GjW.png). I want to save data of list to my SQL database, i can save one data, but when i try to add more it caused error like this "Procedure or function Music_Add has too many arguments specified". Can someone help me how to fix that error... Thanks...
Here is the code to save the list to database:

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = dtuser;
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Music_Add", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        foreach (var item in fav_list.Items)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@music", item.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You can only assign each parameter once.

Comment: And by "assign", McNets means "add". Once added, you can [re-]assign the `Value` property each time through the loop. The good news is that this will force you to stop using `AddWithValue`, since [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: What does your Stored Procedure definition look like - as in, what parameters is it expecting (I'm guessing only @music OR @username)

Comment: my stored procedure looks like this:
INSERT INTO Music(username, music)
VALUES (username, music)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something more like this:

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = dtuser;
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand("Music_Add", "conn str here");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, COLUMN_SIZE_HERE);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@music", SqlDbType.VarChar, COLUMN_SIZE_HERE);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    foreach (var item in fav_list.Items)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;
        cmd.Parameters["@music"].Value = item.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

- Use the string/string version of SqlCommand; it's one less thing to dispose and also leads you not into the temptation of keeping ahold of SqlConnection variables; easy to forget to close it (or suffer an exception and not reach the closing code), and then you leak conenctions. You only really need to carry SqlConnections around if you're enrolling multiple commands in a transaction
- Use `using` - it doesn't forget to dispose, even if an error occurs
- Create your parameters once, and use the same size in the param as the column is wide. See Dan Guzman's blog about using [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - I'm overjoyed to read a question that actually parameterizes instead of risking SQL Injection, but be aware that there are potential performance penalties to using AddWithValue in some circumstances. It's unlikely to affect you in this case, but generally *on SQLServer* it's only one rule of thumb to remember, to get into the habit of avoiding AWV rather than try and work out when it's safe and when it's a problem
- Repeatedly set your values in the loop and execute the query. You could even consider batching with a table valued parameter set, for better performance

Comment: You're most welcome. If this answer contained the info you used to solve your problem you can click the gray check mark on the left of the answe to turn it green. This changes the appearance of the question on the dashboard so that people know you're no longer looking for an answer